# No Resource Manager in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

There's no Resource Manager in my Android Studio. Do I have a limited version or why it's not there?

[image]

All help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because some Gradle sync problem, so see the Gradle output.

My particular problem was because of missing any available (downloaded) SDK:

```
Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 not accepted.
```

Answer (score 0):

hi I had same problem just I fallow this link it solve it easy

https://programmerah.com/could-not-install-gradle-distribution-29866/

Solution:
(1) click the link in the error message:
1 https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
Download the compressed package to the specified path and unzip it
(2) click file – & gt; Settings-> Build, Execution,Deployment-> Build Tools-> Gradle, in the gradle projects area, change use gradle from to your own download path, retry: